# Creating a dropdown/dropup menu with vanilla JavaScript in 2018 (ES 6/7?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following frontend code for a responsive navigation menu.

### Code

```css
media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .burger {
    display: block
  }
  .menu {
    display: none
  }
}

media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .burger {
    display: none
  }
  .menu {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">BARS</div>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>Homepage</li>
  <li>Contact_us</li>
</ul>
```

### My desire

I desire that clicking on the burger elment (appearing for mobiles and tablets) will cause the `menu` element to appear or disappear, in a dropdown or dropup respectively, but without a breakpoint conflict.

To me, a "brakepoint conflict" is when surfing from desktop, we resize a `Xpx>=968px` browser window to `Xpx<=967px` then resizing back to `Xpx>=968px` and the menu stays open and cliking the burger won't eliminate it (won't change `display` back to `none`).

### My question

Is there any pattern (likely with a dedicated [method](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp)) in vanilla JavaScript in 2018 (ES6/7?) to make a onclick dropdown/dropup menu?

Comment: No, to my knowledge there aren't any functions in vanilla JS Specifically for dropdown menus using an onclick handler.

Comment: There is a way by making burger a label for a checkbox, and with css hiding the checkbox and using it's state to show/hide the dropdown, that's pure css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, that's no JS but works :p

I removed the `media screen` for anyone to test even on bigger screen

here's [a code pen](https://codepen.io/shayhowe/pen/zCkBv) from [this site](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/) with a more complete answer

```css
#burger {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

#burger:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="burger">Bars</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="burger">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Homepage</li>
      <li>Contact_us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

adding decoration to your label can be needed to show user they can click on this text